# Rails conditional logic not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions, braintree, braintree-rails

I have a controller action in rails that is supposed to check if the current braintree status of a transaction is either "submitted_for_settlement" or "authorized" and then **void** the transaction but if the status is "settled" then **refund** the transaction. Somehow the controller is voiding all transactions and not working like I want it to. Here is a sample of my code:

```
@transaction = Braintree::Transaction.find(@id)
if @transaction.status == "authorized" || "submitted_for_settlement" 
  @result = Braintree::Transaction.void(@id)       
elsif @transaction.status == "settled"
   @result = Braintree::Transaction.refund(@id)            
end  


if @result.success?  
@order.update(status: "voided")
 redirect_to orders_path, notice: "transaction successfully voided  "
elsif @result.transaction

 redirect_to orders_path, alert: "transaction could not be cancelled code: #{@result.transaction.processor_response_code} text: #{@result.transaction.processor_response_text}"

else
      errors = @result.errors.map { |error| "Error: #{error.code}: #{error.message}" }
      flash[:error] = errors
      redirect_to orders


end
```

I am getting an error on transactions that are settled that says" Transactions can only be voided if they are authorized or submitted_for_settlement" but all transactions that are authorized and submitted for settlement are firing correctly.

What is even more troubling is the controller will void the status in the database even when I get the error and the braintree settled transactions remain unchanged.

why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
if @transaction.status == "authorized" || "submitted_for_settlement"
```

to

```
@transaction.status == "authorized" || @transaction.status == "submitted_for_settlement"
```

Because `==` has higher priority than `||`, `@transaction.status == "authorized" || "submitted_for_settlement"` is equivalent to `(@transaction.status == "authorized") || "submitted_for_settlement"`. So if the status is "authorized", this expression returns `true`, otherwise it returns the string `"submitted_for_settlement"`, which is also considered truthy in Ruby.

I'd suggest to define some methods to the `Braintree::Transaction`:

```
class Braintree::Transaction
  %w(authorized submitted_for_settlement settled).each do |status|
    define_method("#{status}?") do
      self.status == status
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller

```
if @transaction.authorized? || @transaction.submitted_for_settlement?
  # ...
elsif @transaction.settled?
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I tried it and now am getting an undefined method "success?" for nil:NilClass error

Comment: Then what's the return value of `void` or `refund`? What if `@transaction` is not authorized, submitted_for_settlement or settled?

Comment: I checked the transaction.status braintree is sending back and its showing up as "settled". That is a rails error caused by the logic. I am getting the error because the api call is never made and I am checking for a result that was never sent. If the status was anything other than authorized, submitted_for_settlement or settled it would show here:                                       redirect_to orders_path, alert: "transaction could not be cancelled code: #{@result.transaction.processor_response_code} text: #{@result.transaction.processor_response_text}"n

Comment: Where would you suggest adding the class class Braintree::Transaction? Will it be globally accessed throughout the entire rails application ?

Comment: In ruby, classes are always globally accessible.